# Deserialize ArrayList: [unchecked] unchecked conversion required: ArrayList<Employee> found: ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, deserialization

I am trying out serializing and deserializing a java application. It's working but I would like to know if I am doing this process correctly. I am serializing the ArrayList; is this the proper way or should I be serializing the Employee class, but how would I go about that considering we could have many employees?

The way I am doing it causes this error which I would like to get rid of:

> serialTest.java:40: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
>                   employees = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();   required: ArrayList   found:    ArrayList 1 warning

Here is the Employee class:
    package serialTest;
    import java.io.Serializable;

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    int id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }
}
```

And here is the main class:

```
package serialTest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class serialTest {

    static ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            deSerialize();
        } else {
            employees.add(new Employee(1, "John", "Doe"));
            employees.add(new Employee(2, "Jane", "Doe"));
            serialize();
        }
    }

    private static void serialize() {
        System.out.println("Serializing...");
        try {
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("employeeData"); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
                oos.writeObject(employees);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    }

    private static void deSerialize() {
        System.out.println("DeSerializing...");
        try {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("employeeData");
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {

                employees = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("File problems");
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Class problems");
            return;
        }

        for (Employee info : employees) {
            System.out.println(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using raw types when casting the result from `ois.readObject()` to `ArrayList`

Comment: The same thing happens if I do: `employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) ois.readObject();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. Would appreciate some comments.

```
package serialTest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class serialTest {

    static ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            deSerialize();
        } else {
            employees.add(new Employee(1, "John", "Doe"));
            employees.add(new Employee(2, "Jane", "Doe"));
            serialize();
        }
    }

    private static void serialize() {
        System.out.println("Serializing...");
        try {
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("employeeData"); 
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
                oos.writeObject((Employee[]) employees.toArray(new Employee[employees.size()]));
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
    }

    private static void deSerialize() {
        System.out.println("DeSerializing...");
        try {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("employeeData");
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {

                employees.addAll(Arrays.asList((Employee[]) ois.readObject()));
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("File problems");
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Class problems");
            return;
        }

        for (Employee info : employees) {
            System.out.println(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a workaround,  with no actual advantage to my solution below. There will still be an exception if the object being deserialized is e.g. a `List<String>` instead of `List<Employee>`. Java cannot verify that during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to suppress that warning. Java doesn't know the actual generic type due to type erasure.

Comment: Suppress the warning? That's not an acceptable answer. I do not want to suppress the warning. I want a solution for this problem.

Comment: Well, there is no other solution, so that is an acceptable answer. If you would do some research on your own about the type erasure, you would find out. Not everything you want is possible, get used to it.